# Windows 10 store error when Starting Download

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-store-app, windows-store

Recently installed Windows 10 and am unable to install apps from the Windows Store. When I click "Install" on a game or application, "Starting download" is shown. After a few seconds, I get error code 0x80072F8F and the download stops.

I've looked online for a solution but haven't found on that works. Any idea of a fix?

Note: I have tried WSReset.exe to no avail. [image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

The `0x80072F8F` means `ERROR_INTERNET_DECODING_FAILED` or `ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE`. So you have some kind of network issues. Disable your Anti- Virus suite, make sure the DNS Client and the (Windows) Firewall services run.