# Win 10 Store 0x80070057

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I am trying to download apps like Messenger or Feedback Hub for example but Windows Store returns following message: "Try Again. An error occurred. The error code is 0x80070057, in case you need it.".
I have tried WSReset.exe, I have also tried adding a folder called "cache" in following location:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
```

Which by the way worked, but didn't fix the problem when I ran the troubleshooter. The troubleshooter can't fix the problem, because it can't fix the problem automatically and returns "X Windows Store-cache may be damaged".
Is there any fix so that I can update apps and install new apps again?

I have also tried following:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-store-error-0x80070057/f7d0346b-2121-4de0-babc-e53cade30c40?auth=1

[Windows 10 store error when Starting Download](https://superuser.com/questions/991434/windows-10-store-error-when-starting-download)

And ofcourse a lot of youtube videos on how to solve the problem, but unfortunately nothing worked.

Edit:
There is no output from today when I last tried to install in eventvwr.msc -> Apps and servicelogs -> Mircosoft -> Windows -> (AppxPackagingOM -> Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational or AppXDeployment-Server -> Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational).

Comment: A clean boot which most people talk about, fixed my problem but only temporary which means I don't know where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a single app can be the problem, and the answers here helped a little but the app that was causing me trouble is called Cybereason Ransomfreeware against ransomfreeware attacks to the computer. Disabling it for 1 hour made it possible to install apps to the computer again.

Edit: The application got updated which solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Wish I saw your comment earlier.... Would have saved me a lot of time...
The problem with Ransomefree is that it does not update automatically, even if there is a new update. So some of my PCs were fine, because they were updated to v 2.3.0.0 , but two PCs were still on v 2.2.5.1 , which is not compatible with Windows 10 creator (1703). Once I updated Windows to that version, the problems with Windows Update and the Store app started.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have already done [Clear & Reset Windows Store Cache](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-windows-store-cache)
using `WSReset.exe`.

You could also try to [Re-register Windows Store Apps](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/re-register-windows-store-apps) :

1. Create a System Restore Point first, just in case
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, type powershell and right-click
   `Windows PowerShell` from the results and choose Run as administrator.
3. In the PowerShell window, type the following command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
   ```
4. Once the command is successfully executed, close Windows PowerShell and reboot.

Comment: If you look at the image here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqazXrhcOoQcjDuSMHuM6ECeub8f I got one error from the PowerShell command.

Comment: Have you executed `WSReset.exe` using Run as administrator? Try also the other tips in [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tips-fix-windows-store-app-issues-windows-10/).

Comment: Yes I did execute WEReset.exe as administrator

Comment: Try: (1) Reset from Settings > System > Apps & features > click Store > Advanced. Once Reset completes, a check sign appears next to the Reset button. (2) See Part Two in [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15057-clear-reset-store-cache-windows-10-a.html). (3) Delete *the contents* of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore` and `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and try Settings > Update & security > Windows Update. (4) Use the [SFC and DISM Commands](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

The steps below could help:
Method 1: [Run app troubleshooter.](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab)
This tool can automatically identify and fix some issues with apps and Windows store.

Method 2: Please disable proxy, if you are using proxy connection.
a. Click the Gearbox at the top right corner in internet explorer.
b. Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.
c. Click the Connections tab, and then click LAN settings.
d. Uncheck the box next to “proxy server for your LAN”.
e. Click OK to save and close the window.

Method 3: Make sure that “Allow apps to use my location” option is enabled.   Follow these steps to enable it.
a. Press the “Windows + W”.
b. Then type “Allow apps to use my location” without quotes in the search box and hit ENTER.
c. Turn on “Allow apps to use my location”.
d. Then turn on “Let apps use my location” option.
[Source 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/help-required-windows-10-store-error-code/5b83bce7-1059-41ae-93a5-f1f6a6ed2020?auth=1) and [Source 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13765/store-why-cant-find-install-app)

Comment: Method 1: Did not fix the problem.
Method 2: I have no proxy
Method 3: Allow apps to use my location is enabled for each app and didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unmount ramdisk

Here is the reference https://gqqnbig.me/2017/06/04/windows-app-store-error-code-0x80070057/